# MS Access 2007: Manually set relationship type

Tags: ms-access-2007, entity-relationship

Is it possible, when creating a relationship in MS Access to manually set relationship type.

I'm creating a relationship between two tables, where records in table A can be related to 0 or 1 record in table B.

**A:**

```
ID PK, Counter
testID FK
Details
```

**B:**

```
ID PK, Counter
Details
```

I opened relationships tab and then dragged ID from table B to testID in table A. As a result, popup appeared with relationship setup. However, Relationship type was se to *One to many*, with *One* cardinality on the B table side.

Thanks

Comment: You model 0:1 with N:1 but make sure the field on the N/0 side of the join has the REQUIRED property set to FALSE.

Comment: Thank you, this clears things. Why didn't you put it as answer?

Comment: I thought it too trivial to justify any answer, but I've made it an answer now.

Comment: It probably is, but I need an answer to accept. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You model 0:1 with N:1 but make sure the field on the N/0 side of the join has the REQUIRED property set to FALSE.